# Should linked and related questions be the same question?

Tags: discussion, bug, linked-questions, related-questions

I found this question which was rather interesting, and gave it an upvote, and I looked at the linked and related questions as well.

For some reason, the linked question was also part of the related questions.

[image: Picture]

I remembered seeing this happening from a meta post on Stack Overflow, so now I was able to get to the same thing but on Math SE.

Is this really normal?

Comment: Linked questions are those that manually have links to/from the question. Related questions are those that are selected by an algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) according to this very old post over at Meta Stack Exchange: [Linked and Related sections contain duplicate links to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48624/295232). Times may have changed, and recently, a new feature request was posted to have this changed: [The same question should not be under both Linked and Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357145/295232). So maybe it will change in the future.